# How to split a Msg from ValueError?

Tags: python, exception, split, try-catch, valueerror

I have following code:

```
try: 
#do something
except ValueError as e
print(e) #prints 'ABC is not avalaible'
```

Now i want the split `e` using `e.split()` method but it gives me error. How to split this ValueError msg `e`?

Comment: `e` is not the message. You want `e.message.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Cast e as a string first by doing `str(e)`and then you can use split on that.

`str(e).split()`

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found out `e` is not a simple string. So below code worked for me:

```
e.args[0].split()
```